# What is half life of a strand if I have half life of single connection

Tags: probability

I have half life of single connection between strands element. How can I count half life of a strand if strand has 10 of such a connections.

My current approach
Lets say that I have 10 strands, each strand has 10 connections. So there is 100 connections. After time $t_{HalfLife}$ there will be only 50 connections. But I have no idea how to convert this 50 to number of strands with 10 connections.

Comment: Does a strand die when 1 of its 10 connections breaks, or when all 10 connections break?

Comment: One break is enough to kill strand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This assumes that a single break causes the strand to fail.  The probability of no break of one connection in an interval of length $t$ is $\exp (-\lambda t)$.  The half life is $\frac{\log 2}{\lambda}$ as that is the time for half the connections to break.  Given $10$ connections, the failure rate is $10 \lambda$, so ...

Comment: So it gives me $N(t)=N_{0}e^{-\lambda t}$, then $t_{1/2}=\frac{log2}{10\lambda}$ -> $\lambda=\frac{log2}{10t_{1/2}}$ so I have $N(t)=N_{0}e^{-\frac{t (log2)}{10t_{1/2}}}$. Is it correct ?

Comment: @Darqer:  Looks good.